# Is a connected Reinhardt Domain which containg $0$ necessarely a polydisc?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, several-complex-variables

I'm studying several complex variables basics.

Roughly speaking: call $D\subseteq\Bbb C^n$ the set of points in which a given power series
$$
\sum_{\alpha\in\Bbb N^n}a_{\alpha}(z-z_0)^{\alpha}
$$
converges normally.

Call $B$ the set of $z$'s such that $|a_{\alpha}(z-z_0)^{\alpha}|<c$ for all $\alpha\in\Bbb N^n$.

We know that $D=\operatorname{int}B$.

This allow us to understand that $D$ must be a Reinhardt and complete domain (complete means that given $z\in D$ then, $w\in\Bbb C^n$ s.t. $|w_j|\le|z_j|\;\forall j=1,\dots,n\;\Longrightarrow w\in D$); furthermore these domains are characterized to be union of polydiscs centered in $0$ (easy to see).

We know moreover that holomorphic functions are **exactly** convergent power series on union of polydiscs.

In particular, over a Reinhardt complete domain, an holomorphic function is always represented as a sum of a power series centered in $0$.

Now my book states and proves a theorem which says that the last conclusion is nevertheless reached even if we don't ask the completeness.

Precisely the theorem says:

Let $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb C^n$ a Reinhardt domain, connected, containing $0_{\Bbb C^n}$ and $f\in\mathcal{H}(\Omega)$. Then
$$
f(z)=\sum_{\alpha}\frac{f^{(\alpha)}(0)}{\alpha!}z^{\alpha}
$$
followed by a long proof.

My question is: it should follow directly from definition of Reinhardt domain that, an $\Omega$ like the one in the hypothesis of the theorem should be a polydisc. Hence, why can't we conclude immediately with this observation? (the book presents a nontrivial proof, technical and long).

Comment: The set of points $(r_1e^{i\theta_1},r_2e^{i\theta_2})$, for $1/2<r_1,r_2<1$ and all $\theta_1,\theta_2$ is Reinhardt but not a polydisc. The theorem has to prove, in particular, the interestinc fact that a holomorphic function in this domain must be holomorphic in the hole.

Comment: $\Omega$ is connected and contains $0$. Your set doesn't contain $0$.

Comment: Ah, there is a missing detail in your statement that is the point of the theorem. The point of the theorem is to show that the convergence occurs in all of $\Omega$. You know, even in $n=1$ You may know that $f$ is a power series at each point on a disc at the origin. You still need to show that the power series at the origin will converge in the whole disc. The shape of the $\Omega$ enters in play just as in dimension $n=1$. You may be told that $\ln(1+z)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$ minus a line. But the power series at the origin doesn't converge in all that set.

Comment: On the other hand, if we look only at a disc around the origin, in which $\ln(1+z)$ is holomorphic, then the series at the origin will converge in the whole disc.

Comment: As in the one dimensional case, the convergence of the series in the whole domain is obtained from the integral representation that we have for holomorphic functions (Cauchy's theorem).

Comment: I do not quite understand what you are asking.  Consider the holomorphic function $\frac{1}{1-zw} = \sum (zw)^k $.  The domain of convergence of this power series is $\{|z||w|<1\}$, which is not a polydisk.  Does this shed any light on what you are asking?

Comment: Let me think about it. However thanks

Comment: @StevenGubkin my question is: is $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb C^n$ Reinhardt connected domain which contains $0$ necessarely a polydisc? And the answer is yes, and it follows from the definition of a Reinhardt domain. The doubt born because with the assumption of connectedness, the theorem is quite trivial, and it sounded so strange to me. Then I removed the hypotesis of connectedness and fixed the proof in which it was used. It took me all the day but I've done it.

Comment: I think you are quite confused.  Riehardt domains do not have to be polydisks, and my example is a counterexample.  I have no idea what you mean "my series is not a power series".  It **is** true that if $|\zeta| \leq |z|$ and $|\eta| \leq |w|$ then the power series also converges at $(\zeta,\eta)$.  This follows by what freshman call "the comparison test" toegther with "an absolutely convergent series is convergent".

Comment: Ok you're right. I was effectively confused (I'm also tired!). Your series is a power series and your domain is Reinhardt and log convex. Reinhardt domain are characterized to be union of "polymultiannulus" centered in $0$ (a multi annulus in $\Bbb C$ is defined to be more then one annlus; then a polymultiannulus is the cartesian product of such objects). But I didn't wrote that a Reinhardt domain must be a polydisc. I wrote that a R. dom which is **connected** and **contains $0$** has to be such! Do you agree with this?

Comment: In effect your domain is $\{|z||w|<1\}=\bigcup_{r>0}\{|z|<1/r,|w|<r\}$ which is not a polydisc but union of them.

Comment: @Joe My domain is connected and contains 0.  it is not a polydisk.  I think the matter is settled?

Comment: what the hell... thanks; many thanks Steven

Comment: @StevenGubkin However: do you agree with me that the theorem I wrote in the post above holds even if the domain is not connected?; moreover a Reinhardt connected domain which contains $0$ is not necessarely a polydisc, but a union of them, right?! Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20495/discussion-between-steven-gubkin-and-joe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is in the comments already, but I will spell it out in an answer here.

$$f(z,w) = \frac{1}{1-zw} = \sum_{0}^\infty z^kw^k$$ has domain of convergence $\{(z,w):|z||w|<1\}$, which is certainly not a polydisk, although it is connected and contains $0$.

It is true that if a connected Rienhardt domain $\Omega$ contains $0$, and $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$, then the power series of $f$ converges to $f$ normally on $\Omega$.

From further discussion, it seems OP was confused about why the proof of this theorem is hard.  He thought "such a domain must be the union of polydisks centered at 0, and for polydisks it is easy".

The key word missing in the theorem above, which makes it a hard theorem, is the word "complete" before Reinhardt.  For example, the theorem would even apply to the domain

$$\Omega = \{ (z,w) : |z|<1, |w|<1\} \cup \{(z,w): \frac{1}{2}<|z|<2, |w|<2\}$$

which is **not** a union of polydisks centered at $0$.  The fact that all holomorphic functions on $\Omega$ have their power series converge normally to them on all of $\Omega$ is really surprising.   You would think it would only converge on the largest polydisk contained in it, namely the polydisk of radius $1$.  The theorem guarentees that it converges on the whole thing.

In fact, every holomorphic function on a Reinhardt domain must converge on a (potentially) larger one:  namely the smallest complete log convex Reinhardt domain containing the given one.  This is an instance of the "Hartog's extension phenomenon".

Comment: One last question: is your $\Omega$ connected? I'd wrote
$\Omega = \{ (z,w) : |z|<1, |w|<1\} \cup \{(z,w): \frac12<|z|<2, |w|<2\}$. This is certantly connected and still verifies what we want. Do you agree? For the rest, you was really clear, I understood everything. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, sorry.  I did want the two domains to overlap!  Your example is correct.